# Get a result of sub documents located in arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Let's say that I have a database collection called `users` in mongodb and the documents look like this:

```
[{
  _id: 'userId1'
  actions: [{
    name: 'SingUp',
    data: '...',
    time: '1'
  }, {
    name: 'CreatePost',
    data: '...',
    time: '4'
  }]
}, {
  _id: 'userId2'
  actions: [{
    name: 'SingUp',
    data: '...',
    time: '2'
  }, {
    name: 'CreatePost',
    data: '...',
    time: '3'
  }, {
    name: 'CreatePost',
    data: '...',
    time: '5'
  }]
}]
```

What would be the most efficient way to get only the action documents that have the name CreatePost, all sorted by time? I.e. the result I want is this:

```
[{
  name: 'CreatePost',
  data: '...',
  time: '3'
}, {
  name: 'CreatePost',
  data: '...',
  time: '4'
}, {
  name: 'CreatePost',
  data: '...',
  time: '5'
}]
```

Comment: It would be most efficient to use a `$filter` operation in a `$project` stage as an aggregation operation. However you cannot "sort" the inner array without resulting to an `$unwind`, which drops efficiency significantly. Of course if you can accept that the array is always sorted with every write operation and does not need to be re-ordered, then the  `$filter` approach becomes viable. So the most efficient is to maintain the array in an ordered state, rather than trying to alter the returned result.

Comment: I can assume that each array is sorted but there can be mixed sorting between arrays as in the example above where the first and last element of the result is in the second document, and the middle element of the result is in the first document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick solution is to use **`$unwind`**, filter out documents with **`$match`** and finally sort using **`$sort`** like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$actions"},
  {$match: {"actions.name": "CreatePost"}},
  {$project: {"name": "$actions.name", "data": "$actions.data", "time": "$actions.time"}},  
  {$sort: {"time": 1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. Just one comment: To get the result I specify, sorting should be 1 and not -1.

Do you know anything about the performance for this solution?

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson the `$unwind` operator can be quite expansive, an other solution would be to user `$filter` in a `$project` stage, but I'm not sure about the performance difference between these two options